# adjusted bootstrap confidence intervals (BCa) with parametric bootstrap in boot package

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I am attempting to use `boot.ci` from R's `boot` package to calculate bias- and skew-corrected bootstrap confidence intervals from a parametric bootstrap. From my reading of the man pages and experimentation, I've concluded that I have to compute the jackknife estimates myself and feed them into `boot.ci`, but this isn't stated explicitly anywhere. I haven't been able to find other documentation, although to be fair I haven't looked at the original Davison and Hinkley book on which the code is based ...

If I naively run `b1 <- boot(...,sim="parametric")` and then `boot.ci(b1)`, I get the error `influence values cannot be found from a parametric bootstrap`.  This error occurs if and only if I specify `type="all"` or `type="bca"`; `boot.ci(b1,type="bca")` gives the same error.  So does `empinf(b1)`.  The only way I can get things to work is to explicitly compute jackknife estimates (using `empinf()` with the `data` argument) and feed these into `boot.ci`.

Construct data:

```
set.seed(101)
d <- data.frame(x=1:20,y=runif(20))
m1 <- lm(y~x,data=d)
```

Bootstrap:

```
b1 <- boot(d$y,
           statistic=function(yb,...) {
             coef(update(m1,data=transform(d,y=yb)))
           },
           R=1000,
           ran.gen=function(d,m) {
             unlist(simulate(m))
           },
           mle=m1,
           sim="parametric")
```

Fine so far.

```
boot.ci(b1)
boot.ci(b1,type="bca")
empinf(b1)
```

all give the error described above.

This works:

```
L <- empinf(data=d$y,type="jack",
            stype="i",
            statistic=function(y,f) {
              coef(update(m1,data=d[f,]))
            })

boot.ci(b1,type="bca",L=L)
```

Does anyone know if this is the way I'm supposed to be doing it?

**update**: The original author of the `boot` package responded to an e-mail:

> ... you are correct that the issue is that you are doing a
>   parametric bootstrap. The bca intervals implemented in boot are
>   non-parametric intervals and this should have been stated
>   explicitely somewhere.  The formulae for parametric bca intervals
>   are not the same and depend on derivatives of the least favourable
>   family likelihood when there are nuisance parameters as in your
>   case.  (See pp 206-207 in Davison & Hinkley) empinf assumes that the
>   statistic is in one of forms used for non-parametric bootstrapping
>   (which you did in your example call to empinf) but your original
>   call to boot (correctly) had the statistic in a different form
>   appropriate for parametric resampling.
>
> You can certainly do what you're doing but I am not sure of the
>   theoretical properties of mixing parametric resampling with
>   non-parametric interval estimation.

Comment: I perhaps have an advantage in that I have the book and it has a whole chapter on regression applications. I cannot tell, however, whether it would be useful to post my results of using `jack.after.boot` since you say you are convinced that the jackknife needs to be done first.

Answer (score 6):

After looking at the boot.ci page I decided to use a boot-object constructed along the lines of an example in Ch 6 of Davison and Hinkley and see whether it generated the errors you observed. I do get a warning but no errors.:

```
require(boot) 
lmcoef <- function(data, i){
      d <- data[i, ]
      d.reg <- lm(y~x, d)
      c(coef(d.reg)) }
lmboot <- boot(d, lmcoef, R=999)
m1
boot.ci(lmboot, index=2)   # I am presuming that the interest is in the x-coefficient
#----------------------------------
BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
Based on 999 bootstrap replicates

CALL : 
boot.ci(boot.out = lmboot, index = 2)

Intervals : 
Level      Normal              Basic         
95%   (-0.0210,  0.0261 )   (-0.0236,  0.0245 )  

Level     Percentile            BCa          
95%   (-0.0171,  0.0309 )   (-0.0189,  0.0278 )  
Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
Warning message:
In boot.ci(lmboot, index = 2) :
  bootstrap variances needed for studentized intervals
```

Comment: hmm.  thanks ... regression was just my example (my real problem is a GLMM), but I will take a look at this and try to figure out the difference between what you've done (which works) and what I've done (which doesn't)

Comment: oops.  now I see.  The key is that I'm using **parametric** bootstrapping, you're not. I think if you re-do this with `type="parametric"` and the other necessary changes (i.e. adding the `ran.gen` function, etc.) that you'll end up with something that looks a lot like my example above and doesn't provide BCa estimates without semi-manual jackknife calculations ...

Comment: What value does the `type="parametric"` provide in that construction? A linear (or linear on some other transformed scale) coefficient is a parametric estimate. So After reviewing the material in the 2nd chapter of Davison and Hinkley, I think I am doing a parametric bootstrap in the code above.

Comment: I agree that the parametric analysis does not provide any advantage in the example. I am doing a generalized linear mixed model where the parametric bootstrap is definitely different from the standard nonparametric bootstrap, or even than a stratified bootstrap.