# R boot package: Code for wild bootstrap so that BCa confidence intervals can be obtained with boot.ci()?

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to do a wild bootstrap procedure with the 'boot' R-package. The documentation of the package cites the Davison & Hinkley, 1997 book as the source they are basing their functions on.
In this book there is one example of a wild bootstrap (p. 537 & 538, written for Splus) which I adapted in R for a simple OLS regression model:

```
# Fit regression model
model <- lm(y ~ x)
res <- model$residuals 
fit <- model$fitted.values

# Save fitted values and residuals to data frame
data <- data.frame(x, y, res, fit)

# Function for "statistic" argument in boot()
fit.model <- function(data) {
  fit <- lm(y ~ x, data = data)
  coef(fit)
}

# Information & function for wild bootstrap
data.mle <- c(nrow(data), (5+sqrt(5))/10)   
data.wild <- function(data, mle) {
  d <- data
  i <- 2*rbinom(mle[1], size = 1, prob = 1-mle[2])-1
  d$y <- d$fit + d$res*(1 - i*sqrt(5))/2
  d
}

# Number of bootstrap samples
B <- 1000

# Bootstrap
library(boot)
data.boot.wild <- boot(data, statistic = fit.model, R = B, sim = "parametric",
                       ran.gen = data.wild, mle = data.mle)
```

The problem is that if I want to obtain the bias-corrected and accelerated (BCa) confidence intervals for this bootstrap the boot.ci() function does not work:

```
boot.ci(data.boot.wild, type = "bca", index = 1)

# Error in empinf(boot.out, index = index, t = t.o, ...) : 
# influence values cannot be found from a parametric bootstrap
```

As can be seen in the Error message, boot.ci() seemingly can only compute (non-parametric) CIs from non-parametric bootstraps because the computation of empirical influence values (needed for the acceleration parameter in BCa) is not possible when sim = "parametric".

Is there a different way to write the wild bootstrap as a non-parametric bootstrap in 'boot' so that the BCa CIs can be obtained from boot.ci() which is also correct on a theoretical level? Or is there maybe a different method instead of boot.ci() inside the 'boot' package for obtaining the fitting BCa CIs that is correct?

This post ([adjusted bootstrap confidence intervals (BCa) with parametric bootstrap in boot package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7588388)) mentions changing the arguments of the empinf() function imbedded in boot.ci() but there seems to be no definite answer whether this is correct or not.
I have a hard time understanding the difference between a parametric & non-parametric bootstrap and do not know if it is inherently necessary to write a wild bootstrap with sim = "parametric" instead of e.g. sim = "ordinary", since I can only find the former in Davison & Hinkley's book.